# suppose $X$ and $Y$ have infinite elements, let both sets have the finite complement topology. Show that the product topology

Tags: general-topology

suppose $X$ and $Y$ have infinite elements, let both sets have the finite complement topology. Show that the product topology does not coincide with the finite complement topology of $X \times Y$.

If i write out the definition, the basis of our product topology is in the form $U \times V$ with $U$ open in $X$ and $V$ open in $Y$. But this is exactly the basis of the finite complement topology on $X \times Y$, what am i doing wrong here?

Kees

Comment: It is _not_ a basis for the finite complement topology on the product. What is $X\times Y \setminus (U\times V)$?

Comment: $X\backslash U \times Y\backslash V$....

Comment: thats wrong forget that xD, i drew a picture

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{cc}Y&
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\\
\color{orange}\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\color{magenta}\bullet&\color{magenta}\bullet&\color{magenta}\bullet&\cdots\\
\color{orange}\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\color{magenta}\bullet&\color{magenta}\bullet&\color{magenta}\bullet&\cdots\\
\color{orange}\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\color{magenta}\bullet&\color{magenta}\bullet&\color{magenta}\bullet&\cdots\\
\color{orange}\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\color{magenta}\bullet&\color{magenta}\bullet&\color{magenta}\bullet&\cdots\\
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\cdots\\
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\cdots\\ \hline
&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\color{blue}\bullet&\color{blue}\bullet&\color{blue}\bullet&\cdots
\end{array}\\
&X
\end{array}$$

- $\color{blue}{\text{Blue}}$ is cofinite in $X$, hence open.
- $\color{orange}{\text{Orange}}$ is cofinite in $Y$, hence open.
- $\color{blue}{\text{Blue}}\times\color{orange}{\text{Orange}}=\color{magenta}{\text{Magenta}}$ is open in $X\times Y$, but ...

Comment: Is it possible not to use brown in conjunction with black? It's nearly impossible to see. How about $\circ$ instead?

Comment: @Asaf: Grr. I used brown so as not to use red! :-) Let my play with it a little.

Comment: You can't win with colors, I'm tellin' ya.

Comment: @Asaf: Can you live with magenta? Because I really do prefer colors to hollow-point bullets.

Comment: That's better than the browning hi-power that you used before, that's for sure. I guess I can live with your craving for full metal jackets. :-)